# VS2017 Xamarin forms IOS build could not find file xxx.IOS.exe.manifest

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, manifest

I am using VS2017 Xamarin forms, when building non debug version of my IOS project error message "could not find file xxx.IOS.exe.manifest". (I have checked the IOS IPA Option)

I have tried the ios project->security->disable click once, but when I Publish - it is rechecked prior to the build commencing. Tried a new machine build same issue. Patched on both windows & mac up to date with vs2017 & xamarin, not sure what I may have missed.

**Further investigation**
The error occurs when the linker behaviour not set to Don't LInk